# Different backgrounds when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css

I am inspired by this website - http://henrikljunggren.se/ -

Does anyone know how to get two different backgrounds when scrolling down?

Answer (score 0):

On this site, there are multiple `div` with the CSS property :

```
background-attachement: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with the help of css property `background-attachement: fixed`

If you have say 2 sections like this -

```
<div class="section-1">
</div>
<div class="section-2">
</div>
```

then use

```
.section-1 {
  background: url(path-to-your-image);
  background-attachement:fixed;
}

.section-2 {
  background: url(path-to-your-image);
  background-attachement:fixed;
}
```

This will easily give you the effect.